# Error message while setting up VirtualEnv for Django on Mac - what to do?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, anaconda

let me mention first that I just started to learn Django and it seems like I am already failing by setting it up. 
I went to the steps recommended on the 'First steps in Django' page, even bought the book 'mastering Django' and I am also aware that this question has probably be answered already but so far I couldn't find a solution according to my problem. 
So what happens is basically that I installed `pip`, I installed `virtualenv` and `Django`. When I try to create a `virtualenv` I get the following error message:

```
M-MacBook-Air:django m$ virtualenv first
Using base prefix '/Users/m/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/m/Desktop/python/django/first/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libpython3.5m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/m/Desktop/python/django/first/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/m/Desktop/python/django/first/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/m/Desktop/python/django' (should be '/Users/m/Desktop/python/django/first')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

According to the scripts, tutorials etc. I should find the following folder in my new created

```
virtualenv:
\Include
\Lib
\Scripts
\src
```

but in my case it's just

```
virtualenv:
\bin
\include
\lib
```

The obvious question: why is that? I use `Python3.5`, `pip9.0.1` and `virtualenv15.1.0`. I start `Python` via `Anaconda`, downloaded `Homebew` once but deleted it and also the attempt to delete `pip`, `virtualenv` and `Django` and start all over again didn't really work.

Not sure if those information are enough to help. I appreciate any kind of advice. This drives me nuts, thanks a lot!

Comment: The files structure seems to be fine. First is for windows, second one for unix like systems.

Comment: thanks @slackmart for the quick reply. But why do I get the error message!?

Comment: Why is this tagged anaconda?

Comment: Where did you install original Python. Deactivate the venv and type in `which python`